# android.support.v4 где взять пакеты

Tags: android

Где взять эти пакеты? **android.support.v4**

Comment: В каком смысле "взять"? Вам надо импорт сделать или ссылку на исходники узнать?

Comment: Добавить в проект eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо пойти в папку `SDK`, пройти по пути

```
extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4\
```

Где выбрать папку нужной версии (предварительно скачав через `SDK Manage`r).

Там будет файл с названием вида:

```
support-v4-ВЕРСИЯ.aar
```

После этого можно попробовать этот файл подключить. Скорее всего тут у вас начнутся проблемы

1. Eclipse может не уметь подключать `aar` библиотеки.
2. Версию выше `26.0.0-alpha1` вы там не найдёте, ибо все новые качаются не через `SDK Manager`, а с публичного репозитория гугла через `gradle`

Если даже всё получится надо всерьёз задуматься о прекращении использования Eclipse и перехода на `AndroidStudio` и `gradle`, т.к. первый давно не поддерживается гуглом и через `gradle` подключение либы происходит не руками из папок, а одной строкой вида `имя либы:версия`